# Mobile apps development

Tags: android, iphone, html, mobile, web

I've recently entered the mobile world. I want to develop a mobile app that will be deployed on several platforms. I want to develop once - so i'm gonna develop the entire app in html5. I want all the web pages to be on my servers and I will constantly will change and update them. Is there a tool that produce you a simple app that will contain an IFrame to my web pages - so it can be downloaded from the several "markets". I know I can make a totally web app - but I need the "wrapping" actual app. Free tools will be welcomed - but if there are cheap alternatives - they are welcome as well.
Thanks

Comment: I've forgot to mention that I'm looking for a tool that will work on windows OS. Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5662560/1549016

Answer (score 1):

well tool for developing a cross platform mobile app, the best will be 
[PhoneGap/Cordova](http://phonegap.com/) well the technologies used for development with this tool are

- HTML5
- CSS3
- Javascript

with this tool you can also access the device. The platform it supports include

- Android
- iPhone
- Blackberry
- Symbian
- Palm
- Windows phone

Using this technology you can build apps and deploy to app market, google play, etc. popular apps built with this technology are the Diary..Android/iphone.
Hardware specific features supported by the PhoneGap API include:

- Geolocation
- Vibration
- Accelerometer
- Sound
- Contact Book
- Connection

to explore more visit [documentation and demos of Phonegap/Cordova.](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/index.html) and it is a free tool as well..

Comment: Thanks. I have came accross it - but as far I've seen - it only works on Mac. Is there a tool that will work on windows as well?

Comment: If you are going to codesign and deploy an iOS app you will need a Mac.

Comment: dude it works on android as well, as far for now it supports 7 major mobile platforms . there are steps for installation .Visit http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html For Gettin Started with the platforms

Comment: you can also get eclipse plugin of phonegap that will create all the required files for building on android. here is the link for the installation instructions. http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start