# Build application with only web

Tags: php, html, css

Is it possible to build a iPhone & Android application with only web based languages, such as, html, php, css?

I've always woundered that because the only languages i know is web based and i really need my  website to become an app.

Comment: [Yes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662407/how-can-i-develop-an-iphone-app-in-html5)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible, you can use something like http://phonegap.com/ to build apps using HTML/Javascript that connect to a remote server that uses PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple platforms which allow you to make a native application for iOS, Android, etc.. One of them, and it's my favourite one, is Phonegap. You can use the Phonegap

PhoneGap is a free and open source framework that allows you to create mobile apps using standardized web APIs for the platforms you care about. You can easily create apps using the web technologies you know and love: HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Have a look here for more information about phonegap: http://phonegap.com/

And here are some screencasts by Adobe about creating apps with phonegap: http://tv.adobe.com/show/max-2013/